# Query optimization to comapre dates in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, optimization

i was in a mysql competion and faced this problem , i 've written ordinary mysql query with select and compare date but it exceeded time limit  ?
anyone has an observation how to write a better one here ?

btw i don't have extra info about database it self and we can't use indexing here ( only read from db)
Here's problem statement ..

Given a table called "bugs" with the following columns

```
(id, token, title, category, device, reported_at, created_at, updated_at).
```

Find how many bugs were created at "2019-03-01" or later.

It is worth noting that created_at represents the time at which the bug was persisted to the database.

Your query should produce a table with one column called "count".

Comment: What is the schema and where is the query you have tried?

Comment: `i 've written ordinary mysql query`

Comment: SELECT COUNT(id) AS 'count'
FROM bugs
WHERE created_at >= '2019-03-01' ; @B001ᛦ

Comment: no available schema this 's the problem statement only @B001ᛦ

Comment: Your code is correct -if a time limit was exceeded whilst executing then that's not the fault of the query

Comment: @P.Salmon no , it's the query itself i think the key of the idea in " It is worth noting that created_at represents the time at which the bug was persisted to the database. " it needs further optimiztion

Comment: Literally time - or date or datetime or timestamp or unixtime?

Comment: how to implement this ? @P.Salmon

Comment: If created_at is a time datatype then the problem is not solveable

Answer (score 0):

"Find how many bugs were"

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
```

"created at "2019-03-01" or later."

```
WHERE created_at >= "2019-03-01"
```

(That works regardless of datatype DATE, DATETIME, or TIMESTAMP.)

"It is worth noting that created_at represents the time at which the bug was persisted to the database."

```
That just clarifies that `created_at` is the desired column for the problem.
```

"Your query should produce a table with one column called "count"."

Interpretation 1:  "table" = tabular output, a la

```
mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'count' FROM t_county;
+-------+
| count |
+-------+
|  3482 |
+-------+
```

Interpretation 2:  An actual table was desired:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    `count` INT NOT NULL
)
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'count'
        FROM bugs
        WHERE ... ;
```

This creates a "table" and immediately populates it.

"but it exceeded time limit"

Interpretation 1 -- the query ran too slowly. -- Well, I can't help you there without seeing your query.

Interpretation 2 -- the *test* was timed. -- Can't help you there.  Practice, practice.